# How to efficiently compute gradients for each example in a large dataset using pytorch?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch, gradient

Given a trained model (M), I'm interested in computing the utility of new (unseen) examples in a pool (for an active learning task).  For this, I need to compute the magnitude of the gradient when M is trained on each new example.  In code, it is something like:

```
losses, grads = [], []
for i in range(X_pool.shape[0]):
    pred = model(X_pool[i:i+1])
    loss = loss_func(pred, y_pool[i:i+1])

    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()

    losses.append(loss)
    grads.append(layer.weight.grad.norm())
```

However, this is quite slow when there is a large pool of examples, especially since this will be the inner loop in my scenario.  Is there a way to do this more efficiently in pytorch?

Answer (score 1):

Based on the code it looks like you're only looking at the gradients for one layer in the model. You could split this layer into multiple copies, each of which takes only one component of a batch. That way the gradient is computed only for that particular sample but everywhere else batch processing is used.

Here's a complete example comparing your method (method1) to what I'm proposing (method2). This should be easily extendable to a more complex network.

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import copy

batch_size = 50
num_classes = 10

class SimpleModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, num_classes):
        super(SimpleModel, self).__init__()
        # input 3x10x10
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 10, kernel_size=3, padding=1, bias=False)
        # 10x10x10
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(10, 20, kernel_size=3, stride=2, padding=1, bias=False)
        # 20x5x5
        self.fc = nn.Linear(20*5*5, num_classes, bias=False)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = x.view(x.shape[0], -1)
        return self.fc(x)

def method1(model, X_pool, y_pool):
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
    layer = model.conv2

    losses, grads = [], []
    for i in range(X_pool.shape[0]):
        pred = model(X_pool[i:i+1])
        loss = loss_func(pred, y_pool[i:i+1])

        model.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()

        losses.append(loss)
        grads.append(layer.weight.grad.norm())
    return losses, grads


def method2(model, X_pool, y_pool):
    class Replicated(nn.Module):
        """ Instead of running a batch through one layer, run individuals through copies of layer """
        def __init__(self, layer, batch_size):
            super(Replicated, self).__init__()
            self.batch_size = batch_size
            self.layers = [copy.deepcopy(layer) for _ in range(batch_size)]

        def forward(self, x):
            assert x.shape[0] <= self.batch_size
            return torch.stack([self.layers[idx](x[idx:idx+1, :]) for idx in range(x.shape[0])])

    # compute individual loss functions so we can return them
    loss_func = nn.CrossEntropyLoss(reduction='none')

    # replace layer in model with replicated layer
    layer = model.conv2
    model.conv2 = Replicated(layer, batch_size)
    layers = model.conv2.layers

    # batch of predictions
    pred = model(X_pool)
    losses = loss_func(pred, y_pool)
    # reduce with sum so that the individual loss terms aren't scaled (like with mean) which would also scale the gradients
    loss = torch.sum(losses)
    model.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    # gradients of each layer scaled by batch_size to match original
    grads = [layers[idx].weight.grad.norm() for idx in range(X_pool.shape[0])]

    # convert to list of tensors to match method1 output
    losses = [l for l in losses]

    # put original layer back
    model.conv2 = layer
    return losses, grads


model = SimpleModel(num_classes)
X_pool = torch.rand(batch_size, 3, 10, 10)
y_pool = torch.randint(0, num_classes, (batch_size,))

losses2, grads2 = method2(model, X_pool, y_pool)
losses1, grads1 = method1(model, X_pool, y_pool)

print("Losses Diff:", sum([abs(l1.item()-l2.item()) for l1,l2 in zip(losses1, losses2)]))
print("Grads Diff:", sum([abs(g1.item()-g2.item()) for g1,g2 in zip(grads1, grads2)]))
```

The numerical difference between the two algorithms is just floating point error.

```
Losses Diff: 3.337860107421875e-06
Grads Diff: 1.9431114196777344e-05
```

I haven't tested in a larger network, but I played with `batch_size` and ran multiple batches through the network and saw speedup of 2-3x in this simple model. In a more complex model it should be much more substantial since you get the performance benefits of batch processing on all but the layer which is replicated.

**Warning** This probably won't work with `DataParallel`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [torch.func.vmap](https://pytorch.org/docs/2.0/generated/torch.func.vmap.html#torch.func.vmap) for that. It is a new utility in version 2, which vectorizes a function by introducing a batch dimension on it. In your case you can write a pure function which computes the gradient of a single example, and then vectorize it to a batch of examples using vmap:

```
from torch.func import grad, vmap, functional_call

# A pure function computing the loss of the model
def cost_model(in_, target, params, buffers):
    # Compute the cost for a single instance using pure functions
    in_ = in_.unsqueeze(0)
    target = target.unsqueeze(0)

    out = functional_call(model, (params, buffers), in_)
    cost = loss_fn(out, target)

    return cost
# Use torch.func.grad to obtain a function giving the gradient of the loss
ft_grad = grad(cost_model, argnums=2)

# Use torch.func.vmap to vectorize gradient calculation
ft_all_grads = vmap(ft_grad, in_dims = (0, 0, None, None))
```

I wrote that code inspired from this Pytorch tutorial [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/per_sample_grads.html). This is a vectorized code, so it is expected to work much faster than manually iterating over every single training instance.